# In Vue.js.How to pass value from main to compent or template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Example：

```
var index = new Vue({
  el:'#main',
  components: { Index },
  template: '<Index/>',
  data:{
    divCount:'',
    boxs:[],
  }
})
```

and i add compent

```
Vue.component(
   method:
   function(){
     //i wish use divCount in here,and how?
   }
)
```

or

i define a global value in main.js
var author = 'john';

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Index from './Index'

var author = "john";
```

and i wish use this value in Index.vue page's

```
<script>
  module.exports ={
   data(){
      //
    },
    mounted() {
      console.log(author);//it's wrong,how i can use?
    }
}
</script>
```

thanks very much~

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of handling this is to use a JS object for storing your values. This allows you to update them and have the changes reflected in your app. [See this docs page for more info, which also has more information on better practices for larger apps.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch)

Here's an example of how you could accomplish that:

```
// store.js
const store = {
  author: "john",
}

export default store

// Index.vue
<template>
  <div>{{ store.author }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import store from './store'

export default {
  data() {
    return { store }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For **simple application** you can just **use bus instead of vue** : more information at section **Non Parent-Child Communication** in **Vue-Js document** : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Sometimes two components may need to communicate with one-another but they are not parent/child to each other. In simple scenarios, you can use an empty Vue instance as a central event bus :

```
var bus = new Vue()
// in component A's method
bus.$emit('id-selected', 1)
// in component B's created hook
bus.$on('id-selected', function (id) {
  // ...
})
```